# PHP get email attachments through IMAP

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments

The connection to IMAP works and I can list the attachments by name but when I try to save them on the server, that's where it malfunctions.

I tried the code below but somehow my saved files are 0 bytes... what's wrong here?
I do get the files in the same folder as the script so I can rename it later but would like to see the full attachment in there.
I have searched several other questions but none of them really give me a solid answer.

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.server.be:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "user", "pass")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// get information about the current mailbox (INBOX in this case)
$mboxCheck = imap_check($mbox);

// get the total amount of messages
$totalMessages = $mboxCheck->Nmsgs;

// select how many messages you want to see
$showMessages = 5;

// get those messages    
$result = array_reverse(imap_fetch_overview($mbox,($totalMessages-$showMessages+1).":".$totalMessages));

// iterate trough those messages
foreach ($result as $mail) {
    $mailBody = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $mail->msgno, '1.1');
    
    if(trim($mailBody)=="") {
        $mailBody = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $mail->msgno, '1');
    }

    echo nl2br(htmlentities(quoted_printable_decode($mailBody)));
    
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox, $mail->msgno);
    
    $attachments = array();
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
            $name = $attachment['name'];
            $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
            file_put_contents($name, $contents);
        }   
     
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```